# Django Celery One request splitting in multiple tasks

Tags: json, django, web-services, rest, celery

I am looking to achieve something like this:

To have one input json request, which will encapsulate what to do than:

- split that input into 3 or more sub-requests depending on json, like put in database
- an agent will wake up since he is processing one part of that request, like putting data to some server
- another agent will woke up since the request is for him too, he will like upload data to some other server
- meanwhile another request could do state information about request whats part did executed and finished

Is Django + Celery good for this ?

Main goal is to with one request serve parts independently, so like when processing request when waiting for the server in one part of request will not ommiting other part of request which will be processed without any lag.

Answer (score -1):

If your json contains all sub-requests and can be handled asynchronously, seems like this is a job for [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) which can handle event based programs using observable sequences. Best to read the docs first to see if they fit your use case.

Comment: A Java extension for a Python based Django Backend?...